# mustache partial not rendering

Tags: mustache

I am trying to load in an external partial with Mustache as follows:

```
 <script src="mustache.js"></script>
    <body>
         <script type="text/html" id="ul-template">
        <div>
            {{> header}
        </div>
    ...
```

**HEADER.MUSTACHE** (external file )

```
<header>
    <p>header</p>
</header>
```

but it's not loading in. Is there something wrong?

Comment: We're going to need to see your javascript where you render the template please

Comment: @danjam i don't have any, i think that's why it doesn't work, what do i need to write to run it?